# Resize images along with browser size but different % for Landscape and Portrait HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser, resize

I've looked around but am unable to find information on this exact topic and I'm hoping I can get some help.

On my right side of the browser in a table I have an image that can be clicked through with the clickable link. They are landscape and portrait images. The Landscape images are at 900 x 700 pxl and the Portrait images are at 540 x 700. I want the landscape images to only max out at 900 x 700 and shrink accordingly with the browser sizing.

I have been able to have the images resize with the code below.

```
img src="jpegs/pict1.jpg" width="100%" alt="" name="slideImage"/
```

I have the images in the java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var image = new Array("jpegs/pict1.jpg", "jpegs/pict2.jpg", 
"jpegs/pict10.jpg", 
"jpegs/pict9.jpg"
)
```

But, the portrait images gets skewed up to 900 width as well even though I want them to stay at 540 x 700 max and shrink accordingly. Is there code that can be added to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

To shrink the elements you must use a eventHandler on the resize event, get the clientWidth and Height and resize through javascript how much you need to resize. I could give some more relevant code if you could tell exactley the max and minimum size you need and also the maximum and minium resolution on which could be supported this script.

```
 window.$getView = function() {
        var ret = {
            width : 0,
            height : 0,
            element : null
        };
        if( typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            ret.width = window.innerWidth;
            ret.height = window.innerHeight;
            ret.element = window;
        } else if( typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
            ret.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            ret.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            ret.element = document.documentElement;
        } else {
            ret.width = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            ret.height = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
            ret.element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        }
        return ret;
    }

 window.addEventListener("resize",resizeHandler);
 resizeHandler : function(evt) {

   document.getElementById('someImage').style.width = window.$getView().width/10+'px';
   document.getElementById('someImage').style.height = window.$getView().height/10+'px';
 }
```

the $getView function is a cross browser function to get the width and height of the page. the resizeHandler has the math formula to resize the element(s) you want. In here you could add your own percentage of the page and set a min and max width or height.

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering. Minimum for Portrait, 300 x 400 and landscape 520 x 400. As for the resolution, do I need to upload different resolution for each images? The max is what I listed initially saved at 72dpi. I am uploading all images at 72dpi.  As for the $getView function, where do I plug the %?

Comment: i was referring to the resolution you want your page to work on 1024X768 1280x1024 etc, with the $getView you do not have to modify anything in it. it just returns the height and width of the page. in the resizeHandler you can calculate the percentage of which you want your images to get resized.

Comment: Thanks, bare with me, I'm really bad at coding yet I'm trying to code my site myself. So 1920 x 1080 resolution for max and around 1024 x 640 min.